# Quarkus custom rest endpoints with the PanacheEntityResource

Tags: java, rest, code-generation, quarkus

Im trying to work through a few tutorials of quarkus and got a problem with creating a simple REST endpoint. Im following this tutorial: https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-data-panache .

Im using the approach from the guide to create an interface that extends PanacheEntityResource<Entity, Id>

```
public interface ActorResource extends PanacheEntityResource<Actor, Long>{
    
        
}
```

The respective Entity is:

```
@Entity
public class Actor extends PanacheEntity{
    
    
    public String first_name;
    public String last_name;
    public Timestamp last_update;
    
    public static List<Actor> findByFirstName(String name) {
        return list("first_name", name);
    }
    

}
```

As in the guide, doing it like this auto-generates the basic rest endpoints for getById, getAll, create, update and delete. As you can see in my Entity class I have a findByFirstName method which gets all Entities, which match the given method parameter "name" . Now I want to expose a REST endpoint for this method. Ive so far found a way to implement this, but that doesnt seem quite right. Ive had no luck with implementing the REST endpoint for the method directly into the interface

```
@ResourceProperties(path = "actors")
public interface ActorResource extends PanacheEntityResource<Actor, Long>{
    
    
    @GET
    @Produces("application/json")
    @Path("/first_name={name}")
    public static List<Actor> getByFirstName(@PathParam("name") String name) {
        return Actor.findByFirstName(name);
    }
    
        
}
```

No errors with this implementation, but the REST endpoint isnt exposed.
Now as I said, Ive found a way to do this and this is to create an interface as shown in the first code bracket with nothing in it and in addition to that a ResourceClass in which I implement my custom endpoint. To reduce the clutter (in the IDE) Ive combined this so the interface is created inside my ResourceClass like this (example is for another entity):

```
@Path("/countries")
@ApplicationScoped
@Produces("application/json")
public class CountryResource  {
    
    @GET
    @Path("/name={name}")
    public List<Country> getByName(@PathParam("name") String name) {
        return Country.findByName(name);
    }
    
    @ResourceProperties(path = "/countries")
    public interface CountryResourceTest extends PanacheEntityResource<Country, Long>{
        
    }

}
```

This works, by creating the interface the basic rest endpoints are auto-generated and inside the resource class I can add other endpoints, but it just feels like this is not the right approach. Am I wrong, and this is just how Im supposed to do this, or is there a way to implement this with only the interface approach that was originally used in the guide?

Answer (score 0):

I think adding custom endpoints straight to generated resource classes isnt supported yet because this is still an experimental feature for evaluation only. Feel free to give feedback as issues in quarkus' GitHub issue tracker.

I think the best way to add custom endpoints is by creating a second resource class with the same path. Then you can define your custom endpoints there. If you have no name collisions that will work. I tested it with the [hibernate-orm-panache-quickstart](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus-quickstarts/tree/master/hibernate-orm-panache-quickstart) with following code changes:

My Entity with my custom query:

```
@Entity
@Cacheable
public class Fruit extends PanacheEntity {

    @Column(length = 40, unique = true)
    public String name;

    public Fruit() {
    }

    public Fruit(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static Fruit findByName(String name) {
        return find("name=?1", name).firstResult();
    }
}
```

Resource for generated rest-api (remoe the given resource in this tutorial):

```
public interface FruitResource extends PanacheEntityResource<Fruit, Long> {
}
```

My specific resource:

```
@Path("fruit")
@ApplicationScoped
@Produces("application/json")
@Consumes("application/json")
public class FruitSpecificResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/first_name={name}")
    public Fruit getByName(@PathParam("name") String name) {
        return Fruit.findByName(name);
    }

}
```

I also added openapi and replaced postgres with h2 for testing purposes. Here are my dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm-panache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jsonb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-jdbc-h2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-openapi</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-hibernate-orm-rest-data-panache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

And i changed the application.properties to this:

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=h2
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.max-size=8
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.min-size=2

quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=drop-and-create
quarkus.hibernate-orm.log.sql=true
quarkus.hibernate-orm.sql-load-script=import.sql
```

Ok, now i can start quarkus:dev and there will be a swagger-ui under localhost:8080/swagger-ui

The new endpoint is [there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwXXn.png). I tested it manually. It works.